# Hibernate, multiple-where in query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :code ");
```

Say I want to query with 2 columns, one `stockCode` and the other with `stockSample`, how can I achieve this using this ORM mapping?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to plain SQL:

```
from Stock where stockCode = :code and stockSample = :sample
```

Answer (score 0):

You Dont need multiple where statement for that You have to use the logical operators for that such as AND or OR etc.
example:-
 you want from stockcode and stockSample then you can use AND operator as

> `from Stock where stockCode = :code and stockSample = :code`